Let ABC be a triangle inscribed in a circle ω. Show that AC ⊥ CB if and only if AB is a diameter of ω
I an doing this problem, but I am stuck on one part: Let ABC be a triangle inscribed in a circle ω. Show that AC ⊥ CB if and only if AB is a diameter of ω
Its pretty obvious that if AB is the diameter, then AC is perpendicular to CB which can be proved by drawing radiuses. But the problem states "if and only if". I do not know how to prove the opposite - that if it isn't the diameter then there won't be a right angle. How do you prove this?

Are you able to add a diagram to explain the question in a more visual manner? It would really help if possible.

If AB is not a diameter then you can draw two triangles with AB as a base, one using the centre of the circle and one at the circumference.
Using the angle at centre is double the angle at the circumference theorem (and remembering that in this case the angle at the centre will be the reflex angle) you can then show that since the angle at the centre is more than $\pi$, the angle at the circumference will be greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and therefore not a right-angle.
